# How can I pass token to client side for reuse in ongoing requests when using express sendFile?

Tags: javascript, express, jwt

I'm using node and express.

For this particular app, it's quite a simple one and I'm just using `sendFile` to send an html file as the response.  This javascript in that html makes requests of a separate API using Axios.

We have now added a front end for authentication which sets the bearer token on the request to my app.  I can use that same bearer token for requests to the API that is called.

My question is, how can I pass the token through to the client so that it can then add that to ongoing requests, without rewriting my app to use templating?

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: when the user logs in, you send them the token. Then they will send it in every request. For example when they request that file, they will send it. Or is there something I don't get maybe

Comment: The log in is performed by another system which passes my app a token in the Authentication header.  I can access that header in my express app, but not sure of the best way to pass that to the client side when using `res.sendFile`?

Comment: As yBrodsky said, do just that and store that token in local storage

Comment: There are several ways to do it. But I guess using cookies makes more sense in your case. Attach cookies before `res.sendFile` using `res.cookie('token', YOUR_TOKEN)`. Then take the cookies from the req object using `req.cookies.token`.

Comment: Yes, I think that would work.  I can set the cookie and see it on the client.  Is this "safe" though? I assume other client code could potentially access that.